# are there certain criteria for the utensil we use for washing hands?

Tags: halacha

i remember hearing that there cannot be a spout but must be an equally rounded edge.
is this true? if yes please provide source. THANK you!

Comment: I recommend some superficial improvements to this question, but overall I think it's a good one.  +1.  I haven't got time to edit, but marry up the title with the body, use upper case where appropriate, and remove the thank you. Welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Answer (score 3):

See Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chaim 159: 1,5):

> א. אין נוטלים לידים אלא בכלי וכל הכלים כשרים אפילו כלי גללים (פירוש
>   כלים עשויים מרפש בקר ועפר) וכלי אבנים וכלי אדמה וצריך שיהא מחזיק
>   רביעית ואם ניקב בכונס משקה דהיינו שאם ישימו אותו על משקים יכנסו בתוכו
>   דרך הנקב והוא גדול מנקב שהמשקים שבתוך הכלי יוצאים בו אז בטל מתורת כלי
>   ואין נוטלים ממנו לידים ואפילו אם הוא מחזיק רביעית מן הנקב ולמטה:
>
> ה. כלי שתחלת תיקונו כך שאינו יכול לעמוד בלא סמיכה ואין משתמשין בו אלא
>   על ידי סמיכה חשוב שפיר כלי לפיכך כלי שהוא מלא נקבים מתחתיו ופיו צר
>   למעלה וכשמניח אדם אצבעו עליו אין המים יוצאים וכשמסירו המים יוצאים מותר
>   ליטול ממנו אף על פי שאינו מחזיק כלום כיון שעשוי לקבלה בענין זה וזה
>   עיקר תשמישו נקרא כלי. הגה: וכל שכן כלי שיש בו ברזא למטה הואיל ומתחלה
>   נעשה לקבל על ידי כך (טור ובית יוסף):

From [Torah.org](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5760/behar.html):

> A cup made of any material, including paper or plastic(1), may be
>   used. Even a cone-shaped paper cup which cannot stand on its own may
>   be used, since the cup was designed and manufactured in that shape(2).
>
> L'chatchilah it is not advisable to use a bottle, a can, or any vessel
>   with a narrow opening for washing, since it is preferable that the
>   entire revi'is reach the hand full-force from the vessel from which it
>   is being poured. If, however, no other vessel is readily available, it
>   is permitted to use one with a narrow opening as long as the water is
>   poured in an uninterrupted flow(3).